# Invoke Gdi32.GetObject with JNA

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I've created a native library mapping for JNA in order to invoke the Gdi32 library's, "GetObject". [See: MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

My mapping looks like that:

```
int GetObject(HANDLE hgdiobj, int cbBuffer, Pointer lpvObject);
```

But this signature seems to be incorrect. An invocation raises this exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'GetObject': The specified procedure couldn't be found.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you need is found in the documentation that you linked to. At the bottom of that document is this:

```
DLL                       Gdi32.dll
Unicode and ANSI names    GetObjectW (Unicode) and GetObjectA (ANSI)
```

In other words, the function is found in the DLL named `Gdi32.dll`. And there are two versions, a Unicode version and an ANSI version, with appropriately suffixed names. You are probably trying to bind to a function named `GetObject` which does not exist.

Comment: You can use options passed to your JNA library initializer to handle most of the A/W split automatically.  [W32APIOptions](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/win32/W32APIOptions.java) is used by the [JNA-provided w32 platform mappings](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/User32.java#L36) to automatically map Java `String` and undecorated function names (e.g. `GetObject`) into their appropriate native equivalents (ASCII string and `GetObjectA` or unicode string and `GetObjectW`).